# Trying to submit form with dynamic rows. action="" works, ajax / jquery doesn't

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I would like this output

http://imgur.com/gYan7mg

This is how the output looked via the form's action="" statement.  However, when I use $(myform).serialize() it keeps giving me an empty array.  I need to use jquery / ajax because I need to load in a partial view.  My form follows:

```
    <form id="invoice" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="masteraccount/invoice.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vehicle" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Choose Vehicle:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" name="vehicle[]">
                    <?php foreach($vehicle as $v) : ?>
                        <option style="padding: 2%;" value="<?php echo $v['id']?>"><?php echo $v['make'] . ", " . $v['model'] . ": " . $v['year']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table" id="invoicetable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Part Description</th>
                <th>Customer Cost</th>
                <th>Labor</th>
                <th>Vendor</th>
                <th>Vendor Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr name="tr[]">
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity[]"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="partnumber[]"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="partdescription[]"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="customercost[]"></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="laborcode[]">
                        <option value="1">Mechanic</option>
                        <option value="2">Body Work</option>
                        <option value="3">Paint/Spray</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="vendor[]">
                        <option value="6">KOI</option>
                        <option value="7">Advanced AutoParts</option>
                        <option value="8">Smyth</option>
                        <option value="9">Online</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="vendorprice[]"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
            <!-- <p><a id="lineitem" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Add another line Item &raquo;</a></p>
            <p><a id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Submit form &raquo;</a></p>
             -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:6px;" id="add">Add new row &raquo;</button>
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:6px;" id="submit">Submit invoice &raquo;</button> -->
            <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:6px;">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="opendropdown">
                <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Create Common Invoices <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop1">
                          <li><a href="#">Oil Change</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">AC Flush/Charge</a></li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

<script>

$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var datastring = $("#invoice").serialize();

    $.post('masteraccount/invoice.php', {datastring:datastring}, function(data){
        $('#customerContentArea').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: _“Also, here is my JavaScript:”_ – no, it isn’t, that’s a wrong link. Also, you are supposed to include relevant code in the question itself, not on external sites. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: add jquery code you tried so far

Comment: Sorry about that - should be fixed

Comment: `$(myform).serialize() it keeps giving me an empty array` – that makes no sense, `serialize` returns a string value, not an array.

Comment: @CBroe use  $(myform).serializeArray()  see document here https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

use [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). serializeArray Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

```
var data = $('#invoice').serializeArray(); 
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This unfortunately just gives me an empty array.  Which makes no sense to me because when I submit the form via the action="" it gives me what I want, but I can't seem to figure it out with jquery.

Comment: you will get data in array format .. then you need to create your own oput put ... jouery or javascript not provide you to formate data when you submit . you need to get data and formate at your own ..